# rotating ellipse on screen

Tags: math, rotation, new-operator, p5.js, ellipse

Hi all im struggling to get my ellipse(s) to rotate in p5js any help would be grand!

Cant seem to figure out how to make it work as now it just moves on the screen without rotating... lol. I am new to programing so any pointers would be very helpful!

```
let angle = 0
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background('grey');
  noStroke();
  angleMode(DEGREES);


}

function draw() {
    scale(0.75);
    rotate(angle);

  //base 
//black half
fill('black');
ellipse(300, 300, 300, [300]);

//white half
fill('white');
arc(300, 300, 300, 300, 180, 0, [open],);

//curved bit
//black curve
fill('black');
ellipse(225,300,150,[150]);

//white curve
fill('white');
ellipse(375,300,150,[150]);


//dots for the halfs
fill('black');
ellipse(375,300,25,[25]);

fill('white');
ellipse(225,300,25,[25]);



//center point for testing
fill('red');
ellipse(300,300,25,[25]);

angle -= 0.01;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It rotates, but `rotate` rotates the *entire coordinate system* (just like how `scale` scales the entire coordinate system, and `translate` moves the entire coordinate system).

If you just want the ellipses to rotate, remember to first set the coordinate system's (0,0) to wherever your rotation point is, otherwise things don't rotate over that point, but they rotate over the upper left point of your canvas.

You're already scaling and rotating, so you just need to add in that translation first, and then you have two options: scale, rotate, then translate back, and then draw the ellipses the same way you're doing now:

```
function draw() {
  translate(300, 300);
  scale(0.75);
  rotate(angle);
  translate(-300, -300);

  ...

  //white half
  fill('white');
  arc(300, 300, ...);

  //curved bit
  //black curve
  fill('black');
  ellipse(225, 300, ...);

  ...
}
```

*Or*: don't translate back, and take advantage of the fact that your coordinate system now has (0,0) where the centers of your ellipses are, so just draw them relative to (0,0) instead of relative to (300,300):

```
function draw() {
  translate(300, 300);
  scale(0.75);
  rotate(angle);

  ...

  //white half
  fill('white');
  arc(0, 0, ...

  //curved bit
  //black curve
  fill('black');
  ellipse(-75, 0, ...

  ...
}
```